# Athena - Error retrieving results from Athena query

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am new to work with Athena. I have currently written a csv to an S3 location. When I attempt to query the information, I am not getting the full result in my query results. This appears to be because there is a comma in the CSV results.

The original entry looks like this.

[image]

When I do a simple Select query, the query doesn't return this as the comma appears to separate the result into an extra column.

[image]

I am not sure if it is a problem with SQL or a different issue. Any help would be. greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please Edit your question to show us some example rows (in raw text) from your source file and also the DDL (Create Table) command that was used to define your table in Amazon Athena.

Comment: I am not sure how valid is yout input for the CSV file, CSV is usually a comma seperated list. I assume that is why it is extracted into 3 columns,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your examples I assume your raw data looks like this:

```
Entry1,"['item 1, 'item2']"
```

The default CSV serde (serializer/deserializer) used by Athena does not support quoted fields in CSV. It will see the second comma and assume it's a field separator.

There is another serde called OpenCSVSerDe which supports quoted fields and would probably (if the raw data looks like I think it does) work.

You can read more about all the ins and outs of working with CSV in Athena here: https://athena.guide/articles/working-with-csv/

Comment: Thank you. I had to play around with this a bit. This worked!